# Remove reference errors autmatically

Tags: vba, excel

i have designed a few codes to help remove reference errors however it does not automatically delete until i assign the macro to a button.  i do not want it that way as it would seem unpleasant when i want to present the programme to my team members, and having to remove the errors on the spot with a button. I thought of combining my delete cells code and remove reference cell codes together so that they would run simultaneously but to no avail. Is it possible to combine these two codes to achieve my objective or are there any solutions or coding to remove/hide reference errors automatically? Here are the two codes. All of your help would be very much appreciated!

```
Sub deletetry2()

    Dim R As Range
    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set R = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", Type:=8)

    If TypeName(R) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        R.Delete
    End If


End Sub

Sub Check_ReferenceDeletecolumn()

   Dim rng As Range
   Dim rngError As Range

   Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:G100")
   On Error Resume Next
       Set rngError = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
     rngError.EntireColumn.Delete
     'delete means cells will move up after deleting that entire row

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the issue combining the two or getting them to run automatically/

Comment: both. but if it is not possible to run both together then i need a code to combine with my delete cells code to automatically remove errors without me being to click on a macro @Raystafarian

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to remove all rows containing errors, from a user defined range, this should work:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub cleanUserDefinedRange()
    Dim response As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set response = Application.InputBox("Select range to clean up errors", Type:=8)
    If Not response Is Nothing Then cleanUpErrors response
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
Private Sub cleanUpErrors(ByRef rng As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible to combine it with my deleteyry2 code? because i want it to run automatically instead of me clicking on a button to run it @paul bica

Comment: @Niva the top one calls the second one. You can assign the top one a keyboard shortcut if you'd like.

Comment: as @Raystafarian mentioned: cleanUpErrors() doesn't work by itself (you cannot execute it separately) - the only one you can run is cleanUserDefinedRange() (which is your initial "deletetry2()" but just renamed to "cleanUserDefinedRange()")